# sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame.vizSelect() not working as expexted

Tags: sapui5

I use the library sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame to create a pie chart. The chart only contains two values, and I need the first to be highlighted. By Highlighted, I mean selected like if the user would have clicked it, to stand out and show the summary.

Using the vizSelection like this does not work:

```
    oVizFrame.vizSelection(
                oVizFrame.getModel().getProperty('/myPath/0'), 
                {clearSelection : true});
```

I need to appear the graph showing the relevant value highlighted. /myPath is mapped to the vizFrame.

```
            var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
                    dimensions : [{
                        name : 'Object',
                        value : "{obj}"}],

                    measures : [{
                        name : 'Count',
                        value : '{Count}'} ],  

                    data : {
                        path : "/myPath"
                    }
```

I found this example: 
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.viz.sample.SelectionByApi/preview
Confusingly it also does not act as I would expect it after the end-point was  highligthed.

Comment: were you able to get this to work i am currently trying to do something similar

Comment: Unfortunately I did not get it to work yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('Graphics').vizSelection( selection,{clearSelection : true});
```

you can use this command and it will work:

selection is an array:

```
data[Value:1, _context_row_number:1]
```